# Cant copy file with cp on Android, Skipped, Cross-device link

Tags: android, bash, shell, cp

The task is to copy to temp folder some data and then operate with it.
The command
`cp /data/data/com.vivaldi.browser/app_chrome/ /data/local/tmp/zip`

gives

`cp: Skipped dir '/data/local/tmp/zip/': Cross-device link`

I read that cp cant copy to another device but it is the same volume "data". Whats wrong? How can i do this?

P.S. I use cp because i need to copy more than 1 file at one command, without for cycle